# group items from channel, by 8

Tags: channel, entries

I want to group entries by 8. The last div demonstrates that there might be an exact amount of entries that are divisible by 8.

```
<div class="item-container active">
 item 1
 item 2
 item 3..
 item 8
</div>

<div class="item-container">
 item 9...
 item 16
</div>

<div class="item-container">
 item 17
 item 18
 item 19
</div>
```

I want to do it this way so I can use a jquery slide in effect, when you click a button, it would slide/fade-in the next div of items.

I was able to achieve this thanks to the math count % == 0, thanks guys.

Now I have another question, I need to output the appropriate carousel list links

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myaccountCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="recipes"}
        {if count % 8 == 0}
            <li data-target="#myaccountCarousel" data-slide-to="{if count % 8 == 0}{count / 8}{/if}"></li>
        {/if}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</ol>
```

You can see what I am trying to do with {count / 8} so the html will render like, obviously it is not working, but you can see what I am trying to do, my goal html output would be:

```
<li data-target="#myaccountCarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
<li data-target="#myaccountCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#myaccountCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
<li data-target="#myaccountCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
<li data-target="#myaccountCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
<li data-target="#myaccountCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
...
```

I thought maybe I could set a dynamic variable with doing something like:

```
{if count % 8 == 0}{dynamic_variable == count / 8}{/if}

<li data-target="#myaccountCarousel" data-slide-to="{dynamic_variable}"></li>
```

I know I could use stash to store the variable but I don't know how I would get count / 8 math to work outside of the conditional since the EE docs say the math only works within a conditional, any help is appreciated.

Comment: for calculation you can use MX Calc plugin (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-calculator)

Comment: @MaxLazar thanks!!! that did it, I really appreciate the help and your add-on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that ExpressionEngine includes a [**modulus operator**](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/the-modulus-operator) (as of 2.7.1), you can also use that instead of `switch` if you prefer.

Put the first html block's opening tag and the final block's closing tag *outside* of `channel:entries` and use modulus to conditionally close and re-open blocks of html:

```
<div class="item-container active">                
    {exp:channel:entries channel="some_channel"}

        your output here <br>

        {if count % 8 == 0}
            </div>
            <div class="item-container">
        {/if}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
</div>
```

[EE Documentation on Modulus Operator](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html#modulus-operator)

Comment: Thanks @alex Kendrick, I got it to work, now I updated my question to help answer my other problem, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

[switch](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#switch) can help in this case:

```
<div class="item-container active">
    {exp:channel:entries channel="yourchannel"}
        <img src=".." />

        {if count != total_results} 
          {switch='|||||||</div><div class="item-container">'}
        {/if}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the new modulus operator:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="yourchannel"}

    {if count % 8 == 1}
        <div class="item-container active">
    {/if} 

        <img src=".." />

    {if count % 8 == 0 OR count == total_results} 
      </div>
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```